# Creating a button to save the typed data by user in database when the button is clicked

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

How to create a "Request" button for search box? The letters typed in search box should be saved in database when request button is clicked. I am using CodeIgniter.

Comment: You can simply take a bootstrap button from getbootstrap.com

Answer (score 0):

Your view

```
<form method="POST" action="your-action" >
 <input type="text" name="search" />
 <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Controller

```
public function function_name()
{
    $data = $this->input->post('search');
    $result = $this->model_name->function_name($data);
    //$result is the result/output of your search
}
```

MODEL

```
public function function_name()
{
    $this->db->insert('table-name', $data);

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('table-name');
    $this->db->like('column-name', $data);
    return $this->db->get()->result_array(); //you can also use row_array() for one record only
```